# In my react-native app switching from http to https has caused issues with my API call

Tags: node.js, react-native, https, axios

I'm creating an application in react-native and my backend is a node.js server. I just switched from http calls to https and I have tested in postman and the calls are successful. I also have tested on my website with this and it seems to be working as expected in my local.

In my react native app I get the following error:

> [AxiosError: Network Error]

and I received a similar error when trying with fetch. I've defined my URL with the IP and not with localhost as such: "https://192.168.4.72:8000/api/v1/" do I need to copy my certs into my app somewhere? I'm currently testing on android. I haven't got to iOS yet.

Comment: please provide code when you are tying to fetch api

Comment: It's generally not worth it to set up https for local testing, and the setup is usually taken care of for remote sites, so the easiest way is to use http for local and https for remote